# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity - though my entity has all it needs

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to add some Hibernate functionality to a Spring web application. This is my first time when I use the Hibernate Session Factory to be somehow independent from Spring (I used Hibernate Template and worked fine). Now I'm getting these exception `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity` , though I think the components are well connected. But enough talk, let's show you the code:

Entity Class:

```
    @Entity // javax.persistence.Entity;
@Table(name = "CreazioneV49_Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String sessionId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_SESSIONID")
    public String getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }

    public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }
}
```

Repository Class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class DBUtil implements DBUtilInterface {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mySessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void addUser(User user){
        currentSession().save(user);
    }
}
```

Spring Bean Component:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session")
public class CreateV49 implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private DBUtilInterface dbUtil;

    public DBUtilInterface getDbUtil() {
        return dbUtil;
    }

    public void setDbUtil(DBUtil dbUtil) {
        this.dbUtil = dbUtil;
    }

    public void persistData(){
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("Gigel");
    user.setSessionId("1545645645646");
    dbUtil.addUser(user);
    System.out.println("GOOOD");
}
```

Part of applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.28.233.107:1521/SLRFORM"/>
        <property name="username" value="selir"/>
        <property name="password" value="selir1"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedPackages">
            <list>
                <value>creazione.persistence</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="mySessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

Is it possible that this error to be thrown if the table isn't found in DB?

UPDATE: STACKTRACE

```
    SEVERE: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at creazione.exception.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:50)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:550)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1338)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
        at creazione.persistence.DBUtil.addUser(DBUtil.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy49.addUser(Unknown Source)
        at creazione.components.CreateV49.persistData(CreateV49.java:254)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        ... 31 more
Nov 16, 2011 10:32:36 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: #{createV49.persistData}: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
javax.faces.FacesException: #{createV49.persistData}: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
javax.faces.FacesException: #{createV49.persistData}: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at creazione.exception.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:50)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at creazione.exception.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:50)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat60AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat60AgentValve.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: #{createV49.persistData}: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
        ... 30 more
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        ... 26 more
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:550)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1338)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:98)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
        ... 30 more
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: creazione.persistence.User
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:550)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1338)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:172)
        at creazione.persistence.DBUtil.addUser(DBUtil.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at creazione.persistence.DBUtil.addUser(DBUtil.java:27)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
        at $Proxy49.addUser(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at creazione.components.CreateV49.persistData(CreateV49.java:254)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at $Proxy49.addUser(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
        at creazione.components.CreateV49.persistData(CreateV49.java:254)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        ... 31 more
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

I'm going to try now with `<property name="annotatedClasses">` instead of packages... Though it would be weird to work.

It seems that with annotatedClasses works... The User beans is recognized but I'm getting a strange error though my ID is auto-generated:

```
Hibernate: insert into CreazioneV49_Users (USER_ID, USER_NAME, USER_SESSIONID) values (null, ?, ?)
Nov 16, 2011 10:44:21 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1400, SQLState: 23000
Nov 16, 2011 10:44:21 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SELIR"."CREAZIONEV49_USERS"."USER_ID")
```

I'm using Oracle so I've added a Sequence Generator to my ID in User bean but with no success:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "my-creazioneV49Seq", sequenceName = "creazioneV49Seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my-creazioneV49Seq")
@Column(name = "USER_ID")
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

SOLVED: UPGRADED TO HIBERNATE 3.6.8 AND CHANGED THE DIALECT TO ORACLE!

Comment: What's in your `persistence.xml`?

Comment: @CodeBrickie I don't have one. As you can see, I'm using only annotations.

Comment: "has all it needs" is too strong a statement... Check again!

Comment: Have you tried this using <property name="annotatedClasses">
     <list>
       <value>test.package.Foo</value>
       <value>test.package.Bar</value>
     </list>
   </property>

Comment: can you paste the full stacktrace ?

Comment: @AndreiSfat it's on it's way...

Comment: @spauny Glad you got it working with annotatedClasses. Not sure why that works though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to try

```
 <property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>creazione.persistence.User</value>

     </list>
</property>
```

Comment: I've seen people bitten by this a number of times.  annotatedPackages is just used for package-info.java.  packagesToScan can be used instead of adding classes one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You either need a `persistence.xml` listing the classes that should be mapped or a `orm.xml` with a package tag that names the package where your entity classes reside.

Comment: actually he is supposed to use `javax.persistence.Entity`

Comment: That's why I'm using annotations and that Spring class `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`...to forget about xml(hibernate xml)

Comment: You can't go without any XML in this case.